# Quick code to resize DIB image and maintain good img quality

Tags: c++, resize, dib

There is many algorithms to do image resizing - lancorz, bicubic, bilinear, e.g. But most of them are pretty complex and therefore consume **too much CPU**.

What I need is **fast** relatively simple C++ code to resize images with **acceptable quality**.

Here is an example of what I'm currently doing:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y ++)
{
    int         srcY1Coord = int((double)(y * srcHeight) / height);
    int         srcY2Coord = min(srcHeight - 1, max(srcY1Coord, int((double)((y + 1) * srcHeight) / height) - 1));

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x ++)
    {
        int     srcX1Coord = int((double)(x * srcWidth) / width);
        int     srcX2Coord = min(srcWidth - 1, max(srcX1Coord, int((double)((x + 1) * srcWidth) / width) - 1));
        int     srcPixelsCount = (srcX2Coord - srcX1Coord + 1) * (srcY2Coord - srcY1Coord + 1);
        RGB32       color32;
        UINT32      r(0), g(0), b(0), a(0);

        for (int xSrc = srcX1Coord; xSrc <= srcX2Coord; xSrc ++)
            for (int ySrc = srcY1Coord; ySrc <= srcY2Coord; ySrc ++)
            {
                RGB32   curSrcColor32 = pSrcDIB->GetDIBPixel(xSrc, ySrc);
                r += curSrcColor32.r; g += curSrcColor32.g; b += curSrcColor32.b; a += curSrcColor32.alpha;
            }

            color32.r = BYTE(r / srcPixelsCount); color32.g = BYTE(g / srcPixelsCount); color32.b = BYTE(b / srcPixelsCount); color32.alpha = BYTE(a / srcPixelsCount);

            SetDIBPixel(x, y, color32);
    }
}
```

The code above is **fast enough**, but the quality is not ok on scaling pictures up.

Therefore, possibly someone already has fast and **good C++ code sample** for scaling DIBs?

Note: I was using **StretchDIBits** before - it was super-slow when was needed to downsize 10000x10000 picture down to 100x100 size, my code is much, much faster, I just want to have a bit higher quality

P.S. I'm using my own SetPixel/GetPixel functions, to work directly with data array and fast, that's **not** device context!

Comment: Under "acceptable quality" I mean smooth image, cause now it's to rough on increasing image size

Comment: You need different algorithms for scaling up vs. scaling down. The code you show should be perfectly adequate for 1:100 scaling. Bicubic will give the best time/quality tradeoff for scaling up. P.S. I'm quite surprised that anything using GetPixel/SetPixel could be faster than StretchDIBits.

Comment: @ Mark, you are right, different algirithms are needed for scaling up and down. Mine is very good for scaling down, now I need something smart to scale up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright, here is the answer, had to do it myself... It works perfectly well for **scaling pictures up** (for scaling down my initial code works perfectly well too). Hope someone will find a good use for it, it's **fast** enough and produced very **good picture quality**.

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y ++)
{
    double      srcY1Coord = (y * srcHeight) / (double)height;
    int         srcY1CoordInt = (int)(srcY1Coord);
    double      srcY2Coord = ((y + 1) * srcHeight) / (double)height - 0.00000000001;
    int         srcY2CoordInt = min(maxSrcYcoord, (int)(srcY2Coord));
    double      yMultiplierForFirstCoord = (0.5 * (1 - (srcY1Coord - srcY1CoordInt)));
    double      yMultiplierForLastCoord = (0.5 * (srcY2Coord - srcY2CoordInt));

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x ++)
    {
        double  srcX1Coord = (x * srcWidth) / (double)width;
        int     srcX1CoordInt = (int)(srcX1Coord);
        double  srcX2Coord = ((x + 1) * srcWidth) / (double)width - 0.00000000001;
        int     srcX2CoordInt = min(maxSrcXcoord, (int)(srcX2Coord));
        RGB32   color32;

        ASSERT(srcX1Coord < srcWidth && srcY1Coord < srcHeight);
        double  r(0), g(0), b(0), a(0), multiplier(0);

        for (int xSrc = srcX1CoordInt; xSrc <= srcX2CoordInt; xSrc ++)
            for (int ySrc = srcY1CoordInt; ySrc <= srcY2CoordInt; ySrc ++)
            {
                RGB32   curSrcColor32 = pSrcDIB->GetDIBPixel(xSrc, ySrc);
                double  xMultiplier = xSrc < srcX1Coord ? (0.5 * (1 - (srcX1Coord - srcX1CoordInt))) : (xSrc >= srcX2Coord ? (0.5 * (srcX2Coord - srcX2CoordInt)) : 0.5);
                double  yMultiplier = ySrc < srcY1Coord ? yMultiplierForFirstCoord : (ySrc >= srcY2Coord ? yMultiplierForLastCoord : 0.5);
                double  curPixelMultiplier = xMultiplier + yMultiplier;

                if (curPixelMultiplier > 0)
                {
                    r += (curSrcColor32.r * curPixelMultiplier); g += (curSrcColor32.g * curPixelMultiplier); b += (curSrcColor32.b * curPixelMultiplier); a += (curSrcColor32.alpha * curPixelMultiplier);
                    multiplier += curPixelMultiplier;
                }
            }
            color32.r = BYTE(r / multiplier); color32.g = BYTE(g / multiplier); color32.b = BYTE(b / multiplier); color32.alpha = BYTE(a / multiplier);

            SetDIBPixel(x, y, color32);
    }
}
```

P.S. Please don't ask why I’m not using StretchDIBits - leave comments for these who understand that not always system api is available or acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing it on the CPU? Using GDI, there's a good chance of some hardware acceleration. Use [StretchBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145120.aspx) and [SetStretchBltMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145089.aspx).

In pseudocode:

```
 create source dc and destination dc using CreateCompatibleDC
 create source and destination bitmaps
 SelectObject source bitmap into source DC and dest bitmap into dest DC
 SetStretchBltMode
 StretchBlt
 release DCs
```

Comment: +1: Why reinvent the wheel?  StretchBlt with HALFTONE mode stretching mode produces good results, and will be much less CPU intensive than SetPixel.

Comment: Because it's DIB (device-independent bitmap), there is a chance that GDI doesn't supports desired picture format, will remove alpha-transparency. And it's not really fast to create many picture duplicates, I want to get rid of squire pixels rather then trusting that OS will work this time for this particular case.

Comment: Note: SetPixel is not from CDC, it's my own function, a very fast x-y-to array mapping

Comment: FYI: I was using StretchDIBits before - it was superslow when was needed to downsize 10000x10000 picture down to 100x100 size, my code is much faster, I just want to have a bit higher quality

Answer (score 1):

Again, why do it on the CPU? Why not use OpenGL / DirectX and fragment shaders? In pseudocode:

```
upload source texture (cache it if it's to be reused)
create destination texture
use shader program
render quad
download output texture
```

where `shader program` is the filtering method you're using. The GPU is much better at processing pixels than CPU/GetPixel/SetPixel.

You could probably find fragment shaders for lots of different filtering methods on the web - GPU Gems is a good place to start.

Comment: Once again, I was using StretchDIBits before - it was superslow when was needed to downsize 10000x10000 picture down to 100x100 size, my code is much faster, I just want to have a bit higher quality.

Comment: @VolodymyrFrytskyy: You won't get a CPU based stretch that's faster than a GPU based one, even with your fast pixel address calculation. The GPU is highly optimised for this sort of thing and it is highly parallelised and has a huge texture memory bandwidth.